# Functions downgraded in the I2S library using an ESP32

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, audio, arduino-cli

I am following the instruction to setup a microphone with an esp32 with arduino cli.

Here is the tutorial

- https://dronebotworkshop.com/esp32-i2s/#Resources
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-MPBjScNRk&t=915s

As pointed out in the video (timestamp 14:30 to 15:05), it seems that some functions of the I2S library were downgraded. And, indeed, when I compile the code, I get the following error message:

```
/Users/me/Documents/cs/microcontrollers/ESP32/microphone/microphone.ino: In function 'void i2s_install()':
/Users/me/Documents/cs/microcontrollers/ESP32/microphone/microphone.ino:33:47: error: 'I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S' was not declared in this scope
     .communication_format = i2s_comm_format_t(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S),
                                               ^
Used platform Version Path                                           
esp32:esp32   1.0.6   /Users/me/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.6

Error during build: exit status 1
```

Here is the code:

```
/*
  ESP32 I2S Microphone Sample
  esp32-i2s-mic-sample.ino
  Sample sound from I2S microphone, display on Serial Plotter
  Requires INMP441 I2S microphone

  DroneBot Workshop 2022
  https://dronebotworkshop.com
*/

// Include I2S driver
#include <driver/i2s.h>

// Connections to INMP441 I2S microphone
#define I2S_WS 25
#define I2S_SD 33
#define I2S_SCK 32

// Use I2S Processor 0
#define I2S_PORT I2S_NUM_0

// Define input buffer length
#define bufferLen 64
int16_t sBuffer[bufferLen];

void i2s_install() {
  // Set up I2S Processor configuration
  const i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
    .mode = i2s_mode_t(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX),
    .sample_rate = 44100,
    .bits_per_sample = i2s_bits_per_sample_t(16),
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,
    .communication_format = i2s_comm_format_t(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S),
    .intr_alloc_flags = 0,
    .dma_buf_count = 8,
    .dma_buf_len = bufferLen,
    .use_apll = false
  };

  i2s_driver_install(I2S_PORT, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
}

void i2s_setpin() {
  // Set I2S pin configuration
  const i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
    .bck_io_num = I2S_SCK,
    .ws_io_num = I2S_WS,
    .data_out_num = -1,
    .data_in_num = I2S_SD
  };

  i2s_set_pin(I2S_PORT, &pin_config);
}

void setup() {

  // Set up Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(" ");

  delay(1000);

  // Set up I2S
  i2s_install();
  i2s_setpin();
  i2s_start(I2S_PORT);


  delay(500);
}

void loop() {

  // False print statements to "lock range" on serial plotter display
  // Change rangelimit value to adjust "sensitivity"
  int rangelimit = 3000;
  Serial.print(rangelimit * -1);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(rangelimit);
  Serial.print(" ");

  // Get I2S data and place in data buffer
  size_t bytesIn = 0;
  esp_err_t result = i2s_read(I2S_PORT, &sBuffer, bufferLen, &bytesIn, portMAX_DELAY);

  if (result == ESP_OK)
  {
    // Read I2S data buffer
    int16_t samples_read = bytesIn / 8;
    if (samples_read > 0) {
      float mean = 0;
      for (int16_t i = 0; i < samples_read; ++i) {
        mean += (sBuffer[i]);
      }

      // Average the data reading
      mean /= samples_read;

      // Print to serial plotter
      Serial.println(mean);
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried to install the I2S library with:

```
arduino-cli lib install I2S
```

but got the following error message:

```
Error installing I2S: Library 'I2S' not found
```

How can I solve the problem?

**EDIT 1**

After the comments I tried to Upgrade the ESP32 package. For this I went to Tools -> Boards -> Board Manager, typed ESP32 and got the following window:

[image]

It seems to me that I cannot upgrade beyond version 1.0.6 (under Arduino IDE 1.8.19)

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 2**
Ok I followed the installation instruction on the espressif website and it worked

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: It is not that the library has been downgraded, the message shows that you had very old version of ESP32-Arduino package installed (1.0.6), the current version is 2.0.8.. Goto Tools -> Boards -> Board Manager to upgrade your ESP32 package. You don't need to manually install `driver/i2s.h` as it is part of the esp-idf as the foundation of Arduino ESP32 Core.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @hcheung. I tried to Upgrade the ESP32 package. For this I went to Tools -> Boards -> Board Manager, typed ESP32 and got the window displayed in the edited question at the end. It seems to me that I cannot upgrade beyond version 1.0.6 (under Arduino IDE 1.8.19). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I followed the installation instruction on the espressif website and it worked https://docs.espressif.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/installing.html